# Symbols not loaded, a problem with visual studio or debugger on xamarin project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, xamarin, uwp

I'm working on a xamarin project where breakpoints stopped working some weeks ago. If I open the view listing the symbols loaded for debugging my program I read that no symbols are loaded. I have tried to open the .pdb file manually while running the application but an error occured with description "the symbols are not matching".

The solution has an UWP project, Android project, and a Ios project. By the way I'm working only on the UWP project. The versione of Visual studio is 2019 16.5.3.

I also tried to create another xamarin project with the starting template provided by visual studio and the debugger is working here. I don't know what I could now, I tried a lot of thing to solve the problem: clean, rebuild, delete solution from hard disk, uninstall the application, but nothing works.

One strange fact is that the app version is "changing" (the version set in the uwp manifest), but on the view of symbols loaded the version seems different respect the actual.

Is there anything I could try?

Comment: have you compared the project properties and csproj file of the project that works and the one that doesn't?

Comment: @Jason I'll do it, thanks

Comment: I would also try to delete /bin and /obj subfolders in project's folder. We had a similar problem in java few weeks ago. Rebuild, clean and build did not help, but cleaning it manualy solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to select **x64** in this dropdown and not **Any CPU**, as my machine's type.

[image]

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved your issue by yourself, please remember to mark your reply as answer, it is beneficial to others to find this answer, thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I can't do it now, I have to wait tomorrow.